# Merge 2 Stored procedures columns similar to joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 procedures, one of them returns the following:

```
month | amount
---------------    
1     | 12
2     | 14
```

and so on until month 12,

The other procedure returns different values for each month but still contains the same months:

```
month | amount
---------------    
1     | 44321
2     | 1522
```

I want to merge them both to appear like so:

```
month | amount1 | amount2
-------------------------
1     | 12      | 44321
2     | 14      | 1522
```

and so on...

How can I create a stored procedure that could merge these 2 stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the stored procedure source, then one way is to use `insert ... exec`.

```
create proc merged_procs as

create table #t1 (month, amount)
create table #t2 (month, amount)

insert into #t1 exec sp1
insert into #t2 exec sp2

select
    t1.month,
    t1.amount amount1,
    t2.amount amount2
from
    #t1 t1
        inner join
    #t2 t2
        on t1.month = t2.month
order by
    t1.month
```

If you do have access, it may be more efficient to write a combined query, or to rewrite the procedures as table valued functions, which can be combined directly.

Comment: This works great! Thank you! I actually do have access to the stored procedures but they are relatively complex and i myself wasn't able to join them into one query. Either way this works great though is probably isn't good practice, hopefully I will not need to use this method again in the future.

Comment: For 12 row tables, this is probably fine!